# Cant find Manage Object Class in xCode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to generate classes for my .xcdatamodel entities, but am not given the Manage Object Class option when I click on an entity and select File>New File.  I've looked under both the iPhone and Mac OS X catagories, but it is not listed anywhere.

Here are the steps I am taking,

I create a new project being sure to check the "Use Core Data" checkbox.  Once the project is created, I open .xcdatamodel, create an entity, and add a few attributes.  Next, I click on the entity and choose File>New File, but all I see are only Objective-C, Objective-c test case class, and UIVewController subclass.

Am I missing a step?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Core Data Tutorial for iPhone OS and look at this section: [Custom Managed Object Subclass](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/03_ManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH102-SW3). If you still aren't seeing the Core Data related items for the iPhone OS check the version of the SDK you are targeting. I believe Core Data has only been available since SDK 3.

Comment: Thanks!  Maybe it was just late when I was working on this because I could swear I tried this numerous times without it working.  Anyway, it is working now.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Restarting x-code helped me.